# Should the 'si scivola' in "sembra un posto in cui si scivola" be in the subjunctive?

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood

In Ligabue's "[Cosa vuoi che sia?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zd0RXi0QaKc)" he has the line "sembra un posto in cui si scivola." I was under the impression that the verb sembrare requires the subjunctive making the correct verb form 'si scivoli'.

Is this correct or is something else at work here?

Comment: While I always try using the subjunctive when needed, in this case I'd use the indicative; the subjunctive would be correct, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transform your sentence into

> *sembra che sia un posto in cui si scivola*

and you'll see where the subjunctive finds its good place.

In the shorter sentence you are examining, the entire phrase *un posto in cui si scivola* is the object to *sembra*, so the verb's mood is (or can be) independent of subordination.

I'm not saying that *scivoli* is incorrect, but it's at least rather old fashioned. I'd not use it, notwithstanding I'm a fan of subjunctive.

Comment: +1 I am a fan of the subjunctive, but I wrote an answer (now deleted) in which I stated that "sembra un posto in cui si scivoli" is incorrect. I haven't found any conclusive evidence proving that, so I deleted my answer. Anyway, I still think that "sembra un posto in cui si scivoli", or "sembra un posto in cui faccia caldo", and alike are disgusting to say the least, and I strongly advise against using them. I wish I found some authoritative source stating they are also incorrect.